# jQuery Animate Left and Right only happening once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate some content on my website's carousel so that it goes left or right depending on the button pressed. This is my sample code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="red-bg">
  <div class="blue-bg" id="toAnimate">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some other text</p>
    <button id="leftButton">left</button>
    <button id="rightButton">right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.red-bg {
  background: red;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 250px;
}

.blue-bg {
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function animateLeft() {
    $("#toAnimate").animate({
      opacity: 0,
      right: 100
    }, 500, function() {
      $('#toAnimate').css('right', '0');
      $('#toAnimate').css('opacity', '1');
    });
  }

  function animateRight() {
    $("#toAnimate").animate({
      opacity: 0,
      left: 100
    }, 500, function() {
      $('#toAnimate').css('left', '0');
      $('#toAnimate').css('opacity', '1');
    });
  }

  $('#leftButton').click(function() {
    animateLeft();
  });

  $('#rightButton').click(function() {
    animateRight();
  });

});
```

And here is the link to my CodePen: http://codepen.io/leofontes/pen/NRgOxb

Basically, my situation is that if I press the **left** button first, it works and animates to the left, however if I press **right**, the **left** stops working, only fades out but doesn't go left (right still works).

Any idea on why this behavior is happening or how I can fix it? Thank you! 
If more information is necessary please let me know

Comment: you just the change the code `toAnimateLeft` on `$('#toAnimate').css('left', '0');` and `left: -100`

Comment: Add this line  for both methods `$("#toAnimate").attr('style','');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** 
in your code you try to  right to  left 100px and left to  right

> First ,you  remove your left style in your element or do like this

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="red-bg">
      <div class="blue-bg" id="toAnimate">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some other text</p>
        <button id="leftButton">left</button>
        <button id="rightButton">right</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVA SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function animateLeft() {
    $("#toAnimate").animate({
      opacity: 0,
      left: -100
    }, 500, function() {
      $('#toAnimate').css('left', '0');
      $('#toAnimate').css('opacity', '1');
    });
  }

  function animateRight() {
    $("#toAnimate").animate({
      opacity: 0,
      left: 100
    }, 500, function() {
      $('#toAnimate').css('left', '0');
      $('#toAnimate').css('opacity', '1');
    });
  }

  $('#leftButton').click(function() {
    animateLeft();
  });

  $('#rightButton').click(function() {
    animateRight();
  });


});
```

Comment: add this line for `$("#toAnimate").attr('style','');` both methods..  because of styling problem..this is your exact solution @ leofontes